# How to have PHP in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I tried embedding PHP in my JavaScript code to see what happens. Nothing actually happened. Can someone suggest me a way to do this?

```
<head>
<script>
function myF() {
    n=document.getElementById("name").value
    r=document.getElementById("reason").value
    <?php
        $f = fopen("VisitorLog.txt", "w");
        fwrite($f, "Profile viewed on "+Date()+" by "+n+" Reason= "+r);
        fclose($f);
    ?>
    document.getElementById("name").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("reason").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("register").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("link").style.display="inline";
    alert("You have successfully registered.");
}
</script>
</head>
```

I'm new to all this stuff and still learning. Please try explaining in simpler terms. :P

Comment: You can use php in Javascript, just use like this : **var jsvar = '<?php echo $variable;?>';** now for check you can alert this js variable, this will work if your file have php extension

Comment: Did you save the file as a .php?

Comment: You have to use `Ajax`

Comment: PHP simply prints output. What do you want to do?

Comment: OMG what a questions: how he can use js variable in php code?

Comment: There's no easy way to actually RUN php in javascript, nor there's a common idea about why you'd want to do that :) But you can produce javascript code with php, which implies your server code gets executed (meaning web-server is properly configured, php is installed, and your code is runnable)

Comment: You are trying to get a javascript variable in php. php is serverside and javascript client side, you should implement an ajax request to pass data from javascript to a php script.

Comment: Use `.`-Operator to concatenate strings in PHP, otherwise you will add them with their numeric value, which is not what you want.

Comment: I've put all of this in .html document. No .js or .php file. So, you mean to say that it's impossible to do this? Then how can I save textbox values to a text file WITHOUT php?

Answer (score 2):

First keep in mind that PHP is rendered on the server and Javascript will be interpreted at your client(Web browser). so if you echo something from PHP it will be sent with the html and it won't be executed with the Javascript as you are assuming here.

To accomplish what you want here you need to make an AJAX call to a PHP script which will update your views log.

Edit:

on update.php file

```
<?php
$n = $_POST['n'];
$r = $_POST['r'];
$f = fopen("VisitorLog.txt", "w");
fwrite($f,"Profile viewed on ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." by ".$n." Reason= "+$r);
fclose($f);
```

And on your javascript (assuming you have jquery loaded)

```
<script>
function myF()
{
    $.post("update.php",
                { 
                    n : document.getElementById("name").value, 
                    r : document.getElementById("reason").value
                },
                function({
        document.getElementById("name").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("reason").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("register").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("link").style.display="inline";
        alert("You have successfully registered.");
    }));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Then how do I save textbox values to a text file without PHP?

Comment: Take a look at the edit (it is not perfect but it does the trick)

Comment: Did you add jquery to your webpage ?

Answer (score 2):

The main concept you need to understand is that Javascript runs on the client side, namely the web browser, and PHP on the server. The PHP code you have added to your page is executed before any Javascript is processed.

If you want your Javascript to send data to your PHP application you need to use Ajax.
Using libraries such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com) will make your life a lot easier.
Here's an example of how that can work using jQuery.

PHP - log.php

```
<?php
$string = sprintf('Profile viewed on %s by %s Reason= %s', 
                  $_POST['date'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['reason']);
$f = fopen("VisitorLog.txt", "w");
fwrite($f, $string);
fclose($f);
?>
```

Javascript

```
var n = $("#name").val();
var r = $("#reason").val();
var d = new Date();

$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/log.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {name: n, reason: r, date: d}
}).done(function(response){
    // response contains the output of log.php

});
```

Reference

- http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

PHP is rendered on [server-side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side). JavaScript is rendered on [client-side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side).

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone said. You can't mix server side code with client side code.. php is renderd/executed at server side an js in the client's browser..

If possible separate js and php. A working solution could be: (assuming jQuery for the ajax call, actually another framework or even plain js could be used)

in your js file (or in the script tag in the header)

```
function log(message, success, failure){
    $.ajax({
        url: "logger.php",
        data: {
            message: message
        },
        success: success,
        error: failure
    })
}
function myF(){
    var n=document.getElementById("name").value,
        r=document.getElementById("reason").value;

    log( "Profile viewed on "+Date()+" by "+n+" Reason= "+r, function(){
        console.log('I successfully logged');
    }, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log('something went wrong', jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    });

    document.getElementById("name").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("reason").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("register").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("link").style.display="inline";
    alert("You have successfully registered.");
}
```

in a file `logger.php`

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['message'])){
        $f = fopen("VisitorLog.txt", "w");
        fwrite($f, $_GET['message']);
        fclose($f);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PhP is executed on the server, before the page loads. So your PhP will execute, then the page loads. Then the javascript loads. So your javascript here will not trigger the PhP.

The two ways to do this:
- Run the PhP script when the page laods on the server
- Use AJAX to run a server-side php script to register the userdetails.

Comment: Why do you write `PHP` like that :|

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs on the client side,  php runs on the server side. You need to make e.g.  an ajax call to some method on the server side that will do server-side tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Only the server can interpret and run the php code. Make sure that the file you are editing is stored in a server with php installed (you can try WAMP or XAMPP if you want to test locally in your computer).